# Is there a way to find any number that has been pressed on "pygame"? and how display it?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to ask the user the length of the code they would like to crack from 1 - 7
I also need to account for those using Numpad.
Anyway, I know the code for everything except how to detect the number they have pressed.

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_2 or event.key == pygame.K_3 or event.key == pygame.K_4 or event.key == pygame.K_5 or event.key == pygame.K_6 or event.key == pygame.K_7:
        print(int(event.key)-48)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_KP_2 or event.key == pygame.K_KP_3 or event.key == pygame.K_KP_4 or event.key == pygame.K_KP_5 or event.key == pygame.K_KP_6 or event.key == pygame.K_KP_7:
        print(int(event.key)-1073741912)
```

This is just too clunky and even before writing this code,
I thought it would be ugly to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

A user friendly name of a key can be get with [`pygame.key.name()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name):

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```

e.g.:

```py
print(pygame.key.name(pygame.K_5))
print(pygame.key.name(pygame.K_KP_5))
```

output:

```
5
[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rabbid76's response, here is an explicit answer:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if pygame.key.name(event.key) in ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]:
        print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
    elif pygame.key.name(event.key) in ["[2]", "[3]", "[4]", "[5]", "[6]", "[7]"]:
        print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pygame keys are just subsequent int constants, so you can use a `range()` like this:

```
if event.key in range(pygame.K_2, pygame.K_7 + 1):
    print(int(event.key) - pygame.K_0)
elif event.key in range(pygame.K_KP_2, pygame.K_KP_7 + 1):
    print(int(event.key) - pygame.K_KP_0)
```